# Q promise. Difference between .when and .then

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I though this code will work:

```
var promise = function(val) {

    var _val = val;

    return setTimeout(function(_val) {

        var newVal = val / 10;

        return {
            newVal : newVal,
            message : 'it just to be a ' + val
        };
    }, 3000);
};

Q.when(promise(400)).then(function(obj) {
    return console.log('jaaaaj !', obj);
}, function() {
    return console.log('no yet...');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cachaito/4r78yesq/)

My thinking was like: when setTimeout finish its job after four seconds, Q library will catch return in first callback and show object with two properties: `newVal : 4` and `message : 'it just to be a ' + 400`. Instead I have weird 1 number as obj in success callback...

BTW what is a difference between `.when` and `.then` in Q library?

Comment: You can't actually return anything from a `setTimeout`, because it's async. Also, it should be clear from context (and from the accepted args) that `when` wraps a promise so that it can be chained with `then` which fires the callbacks _when_ the promise is resolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.when()` takes one or more promises as arguments.  You are passing it a timer handle so it will just execute the `.then()` handler immediately.

`.when()` has no magic ability to discern when something you pass to it is done.  You must pass it one or more promises and it monitors when those promises are resolved.

Also, you can't return anything from a `setTimeout()`, but if you resolved a promise inside the `setTimeout()` you could pass data to the `.resolve()` method.

You could do something like this:

```
var promise = function(val) {
    var defer = Q.defer();

    setTimeout(function() {

        var newVal = val / 10;

        defer.resolve({
            newVal : newVal,
            message : 'it just to be a ' + val
        });
    }, 3000);

    // return the promise
    return defer.promise;
};

Q.when(promise(400)).then(function(obj) {
    return console.log('jaaaaj !', obj);
}, function() {
    return console.log('rejected...');
});
```

---

But, when you only have one promise, you don't even need `Q.when()`.  You could just do this:

```
promise(400).then(function(obj) {
    return console.log('jaaaaj !', obj);
}, function() {
    return console.log('rejected...');
});
```

Comment: "You can't return anything from a setTimeout()" - correct, but similarly, you can't pass anything *to* a setTimeout. Any object/value used inside a setTimeout's function must be either "self-generated" (eg. var foo = 99;) or taken from the lexical environment in which the function (but not necessarily the setTimeout itself) is written. Therefore `setTimeout(function(_val) {` can be rewritten as `setTimeout(function() {`, and the line `var _val = val;` can be deleted as `val` is automatically reachable from inside the setTimeout's function (as shown by the line `var newVal = val / 10;`).

Comment: Oh yes, a third way to make a value/object available to a setTimeout's function is to use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), which returns a new function with "pre-passed" parameters (and a context).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - you're correct about not passing arguments directly to the `setTimeout()` callback.  I didn't see that originally in the OP's code, but fortunately for them, they weren't using the argument they had declared.  In any case, I've removed it from the code in my answer.  In this case, there is no need to pass anything to it as it can access the parent scope directly to get `val`.  Yes, `.bind()` could be used, though that is not required in this instance.

Comment: jfriend00, sorry to ramble on. I'm sure you would have got the point if I had expressed myself more concisely. (And I'm not in favour of editing other people's answers)

Comment: Thank You guys. Now it is much clearer for me. Maybe You know some good tutorials about promises worth recommend?

Comment: @cachaiton - There are many articles on the web about promises which you can find in a Google search.  What I've found particularly instructional is to make yourself a saved filter on StackOverflow that watches the "deferred" and "promise" keywords.  If you just read those questions each day, try to work out an answer yourself and then watch the other answers that come in, you will learn a lot.  That set of questions is monitored by some of the key folks in developing some of the promise libraries so there's pretty much always a quality answer you can learn at lot from.